# How to display an error page in case no internet connection in Android

Tags: java, android, webview

I want to load an error page from the asset folder which I've created. Everything is working smoothly but error page i.e. 404.html is not loading in case of no internet. I am using following Snippet in MainActivity.java file.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/404.html");

            }
        });
```

Comment: Why on earth are you using an HTML page for your not found content? Why not just use native Views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this method to check internet connection :

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

If it returns `false` then display your error page

You will need

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission in manifest

**EDIT**  Do like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        if(isNetworkAvailable())
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        else
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/404.html");
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Comment: you can call this method after declaring your webview

Comment: I've added the following code but it is not working. Plz help. 
`if(isNetworkAvailable()==false)
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
} else {
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); }

         mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
            }

`

Comment: Do like this :  if(isNetworkAvailable()) {
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); } else { mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/404.html"); }

Comment: Dont need to compare like this isNetworkAvailable()==false. And you are displaying index.html in both if and else condition. Inside else condition load 404.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below codings to check internet connection.

```
WebSettings wbset=wbb.getSettings();
wbset.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wbb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,String description, String failingUrl) {
    view.loadUrl("about:blank");
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error occurred, please check network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
}
```